# Google plus in android app

Tags: android, google-plus

I am working on an app with integration for facebook, twitter, flicker, and Google plus. I have done all the things besides Google plus.

Has anyone used Google plus API in his own app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google+ Platform for Android is now available.

With the platform, you are able to:

- Allow users to sign in with Google+.
- Integrate the native +1 button.
- Write moments to the user's Google+ history (developer preview)

For more information, see:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no official API for Google Plus for Android. Check out the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/).
Quote:

> The Google+ platform for Android will soon be available in the coming
>   weeks — this documentation gives you a quick overview of what to
>   expect.